# Non-indexed file (?) still found in Google

Tags: search, search-engine, robots.txt, googlebot

How is it possible that my page /admin/login.asp is found in Google with the query "inurl:admin/login.asp" while it isn't with the "site:www.domain.xx" query?

I've this line of code in my robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
```

And this in the HTML code of the page:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that the page existed before you added/adepted your robots.txt? In htat case it might take a while for Google to adapt to the change.

Comment: No, both uploaded at the same time, 4 months ago. And still, why the difference between "inurl" and "site" command?

Answer (score 0):

You can check on [Google Webmaster](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) if the robots.txt is interpreted correctly by Google. You can also request the removal of a URL from the index there.

Comment: Yes, GWT interpreted it correctly. If I look at "Crawl errors"" I even see a remark "URL restricted by robots.txt" for this page on "Jul 19, 2010"

Comment: Sure I can request a removal. But I was wondering why it's found. Now I've to ask for a removal AFTER somebody tried to hack (??) my site :-(

Comment: @waanders: request a removal *and* ask Google why it's still found.

Comment: I did, my request is pending. How can ask Google that question?

Comment: Google has accepted my request, the page is no longer found with the "inurl" query. I'm still wondering why there's a difference between the "inurl:" and the "site:" command.

Answer (score 0):

When you find the URL in the Google search result page (SERP), does it have the same title as found in your  tag? And does it also have a description / snippet?

What I think is happening is that Google knows about the URL from a link on your site, so it'll attempt to crawl and index it. However, since it's blocked by robots.txt, it's not allowed to crawl the page, hence it can't see the noindex meta tag that's on your login page.

Since it doesn't know that it shouldn't index the page, Google will add the URL to it's index. However, pages like this tend to only have a title and URL in the SERP, and they almost always don't have a description/snippet. Sometimes the title in the SERP looks like they've crawled the page, but what they're actually doing is trying to generate a title based on the anchor text of the links that are pointing at it.

The sure fire way of having the page not show up in the SERP is to remove the `Disallow: /admin/` command, and allow Googlebot to crawl the page and see the noindex,nofollow meta tag.

The noindex command will remove the page from the SERPs, and the nofollow will help inform Googlebot not to give priority to the links that it finds on your login page (this will help maintain your crawl efficiency, but does not guarantee Google won't crawl the links it finds on the page).

Comment: I don't know. I cannot check this anymore because Google already accepted my removal request

Comment: But removing the Disallow: /admin/ ? Maybe, but it is meant to prevent pages from being indexed? Anyway, thanks for your help and thoughts

Comment: @waanders The disallow command in robots.txt doesn't prevent the page from being index, but it does prevent the content of the page from being indexed. It's a slight difference, but significant. Search engines will add URL to their index, and even surface popular URLs even though they've never seen the content of the page. The only way to prevent the content and the URL from displaying in the SERP is to allow the crawlers to see the page, index it, but also see the noindex command which really just means, don't display in SERP.